# Ionic Dynamic Toolbar Background Color

Tags: css, ionic2

I have a footer and I want to make its background color dynamic. I am trying to bind the element to a class or give dynamic styling but it is not working. Event it is not taking the style.I have this in my html.

```
<ion-footer align="center" style="height: 50px" *ngIf="visibility">
  <ion-toolbar class="testing"> //or// <ion-toolbar style="background-color: lightgreen">
    <ion-title>
      .....
```

and this in my .scss

```
.toolbar-background.testing {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  color:white
}
```

//or

```
.testing {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

only this is working, but I do not know how to make it dynamic.

```
.toolbar-background {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  color:white
}
```

Comment: `dynamic styling` as in you want to programmatically change the color based on a condition?

Comment: yes, I have an object lets say 'Call', the color depends on the 'Call.status' integer variable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can have it work with this code in the HTML:

```
<ion-toolbar [color]="currentColor"></ion-toolbar>
```

Add your desired colors in your variables.scss file

```
$colors: (
   blue:    #387ef5,
   secondary:  #32db64,
   danger:     #f53d3d,
   light:      #f4f4f4,  // the light color we're using
   dark:          #222   // the dark color we're using
);
```

In your .ts file, you can initialize your "currentColor" variable to the default color

```
private currentColor: string

constructor() {
    this.currentColor = 'light';
}
```

And then have a function to change to the dark color

```
changeToDarkColor() {
    this.currentColor = 'dark';
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It Worked. I think [color]="currentColor" should be [color]="{{currentColor}}"

Answer (score 3):

You would generally use `ngStyle` or `ngClass` to dynamically set styles for html elements. However `ion-toolbar` is a custom component of ionic 2.
Check [toolbar colors](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#toolbar-colors) docs.

Try:

```
<ion-toolbar color="primary">
```

The attribute picks the color from the `colors` map in **variables.scss**.

Add a color to the map. `$colors: (...toolbar-color:green)`

and do:

```
 <ion-toolbar [color]="colorStatus?'toolbar-color':'primary'">
```

Comment: I tried those it is not working, it is not taking the classes