# How to change the toolbar color in Ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am working in my Ionic 4 app and I want to change the background color of the toolbar but it is not working.

**This I have tried:**

```
ion-toolbar {
    --background: #f2f2f2;
}

ion-toolbar {
    background: #f2f2f2 !important;
}
```

Like:

> color: var(--ion-color-contrast);

where to define the `--ion-color-contrast`. In `variables.scss` file or some where else for changing the color.

Can anyone help me how the define the variables in the `variables.scss` for changing the colors in **Ionic 4**.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43910108/ionic-dynamic-toolbar-background-color

Comment: @Hrishi. Can you please help me with proper explanation?

Comment: check answer given by TheAppchemist on above link

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HTML:

```
<ion-toolbar [color]="dynamicColor"></ion-toolbar>
```

Set color in your variables.scss file

```
$colors: (
   blue:    #387ef5,
   secondary:  #32db64,
   danger:     #f53d3d,
   light:      #f4f4f4,  
   dark:          #222 
);
```

In your .ts file, you can initialize your "dynamicColor" variable to the default color

```
private dynamicColor: string

constructor() {
   this.dynamicColor = 'light';
}
```

You can change color by calling function

```
changeToDarkColor() {
    this.dynamicColor = 'dark';
}
```

Answer (score 11):

This should work:

```
// global.scss
ion-toolbar {
  --background: #f2f2f2;
}
```

Just confirmed it on my environment, it's not so obvious with this colour because it's quite light so try it with something darker like `blue` just to make sure it's changing.

Reference [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/toolbar)

The colours are defined in the `theme/variables.scss` file, you can use this handy [generator](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/color-generator) to help create the css which you can then just copy and paste into the `variables.scss` file and then reference the colours using `var(--ion-color-primary);`.

Answer (score 6):

ionic 4 variable.scss:

```
--ion-toolbar-background: var(--ion-color-primary);
--ion-toolbar-color: var(--ion-color-light);
```

for custom page :

```
<ion-toolbar color="primary">
```

for custom css:

```
.my-toolbar{
    --background: var(--ion-color-primary);
}
```