# How to change the toolbar color in Ionic 4 with CSS

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic4

I would like to change the background color through page.scss of ion-toolbar, ion-tab-bar and ion-tab-button.

it works for ion-tab-bar and ion-tab-button but not for ion-toolbar.

there is the code from page.scss:

```
ion-toolbar, ion-tab-bar, ion-tab-button {

    background-color: aquamarine;

}
```

thanks for your help

Comment: Hi JBD and welcome to SO. Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Have you tried inspecting `.ion-toolbar` ? Another element must be overriding your custom CSS. Add enough [specificity](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp) for it to work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the toolbar color in Ionic 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54956372/how-to-change-the-toolbar-color-in-ionic-4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They use CSS variables with Ionic 4, try something like

```
ion-toolbar {
    --background: aquamarine;
    }
```

You can learn more about the variables for the toolbar and other components here:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/toolbar